# Paramiko: Executing a perl script within a shell script

Tags: perl, ssh, paramiko

Hi I have shell script within which a perl script is embedded.

cat chkLog.sh

```
LOGFILE=`echo $1`
echo "#Action15: Check Log" | tee -ia $LOGFILE
perl << '__THERE__' | tee -ia $LOGFILE
print("hello Word\n");
.Some more complex perl codes
.
.
__THERE__
echo "#EndAct" | tee -ia $LOGFILE
```

Basically I am using Here-docs concept to execute a perl code. Now if i execute the above script directly on the server I get the desired out put. But when i send it thru paramiko, the perl part is completely ignored. And the output is:

Output Via Paramiko:

```
#Action15: Check Log
#EndAct"
```

Paramiko Script:

```
>>> hostname='192.168.122.1'
>>> username='may'
>>> password='*******'
>>> setupcommand="/user/may/click_demo_test/chkLog.sh"
>>> resultloc="/user/spm/click_demo_test/setuplog/chkLog.sh"
>>> execomand= setupcommand + ' ' + resultloc
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
>>> channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
>>> channel.exec_command(execomand)
>>> while not channel.exit_status_ready():
              time.sleep(1)
>>> stdout = channel.makefile("rb")
>>> print stdout.readlines()
```

Converting Perl to complete shell will be a hectic task as, I have many scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not checking any return values, are you sure the shell script didn't attempt to run the perl command and fail?  I would suggest checking return codes in the shell script $? and perhaps put the absolute path to the perl interpreter to rule out any environment issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running in remote shell with

```
channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
```

before `exec_command` cause there are might be problems with absence of pseudo-terminal, to eliminate the difference in running directly in terminal and through SSH.

If that's not working, you can try with some simple heredoc without perl and see how it works through SSH, if it works - then try simple perl, and so on.

And yes, try to capture errors, as it was already mentioned.